# Bouncy castle no such provider exception

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I have added the bouncy castle jar file to my application class path in android and in java.
This is the code that I've used in both of them. But it doesn't seem to recognize the provider "BC".

```
SecureRandom sr1=new SecureRandom().getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "BC");
      System.out.println(sr1.getProvider());
      sr1.setSeed(12);
      byte[] a=new byte[0];
      sr1.nextBytes(a);
      int ai=a[0];
      System.out.println(ai);
```

It throws the following exception in both android and in java:

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC
```

How to correct this?
I had not added the provider in the policy file. After doing that I am getting the following exception.

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1PRNG for provider
 BC<br>
```

Does it mean that bouncy castle does not provide an implementation of "SHA1PRNG" algorithm? But the whole reason I imported  bouncy castle was to have a common provider in both android and in java, so that the sequence of random numbers generated with the same seed are the same in both android and java.

Comment: What is target sdk version in your android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't provide a `SecureRandom` implementation at all. You can get the system implementation (from Harmony) like this (no need to create an instance to call static method):

```
SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
```

BouncyCastle has `DigestRandomGenerator` which could probably used in a similar manner, but may or may not be compatible with the Sun SHA1PRNG (which appears to be proprietary, and really well defined)

Re: generating OTPs using `SecureRandom`: `SecureRandom` with a fixed seed is *not* the right tool for this. To generate OTPs, you should use a secret key combined with a predictable element (time or a counter). A standard way is using an HMAC as specified by e.g. OATH. Read [RFC 4226](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) for details.

Comment: I am trying to aceive the same sequesnce of numbers in both the client(android) and the server(servlet).When you seed your random number with  "sha1prng" as the the prng algorithm, it does not add any entropy to the user specified seed. That is why when two instances of a secure random number are used in java they produce the same sequence of numbers. The same thing is happening in android also. But the problem is that the sequences generated in android and in java are not the same.

Comment: OK, I was wrong. It only adds entropy if you call it more than once. Still, if you need to matching sequences, use a database and increment a number. A secure random generator is not the tool for this. See updated answer about it's not so easy to use BC on Android.

Comment: I am actually using the sequesnces as one time password. I cannot use a number and increment it and use it as a otp. yes it would defeat the purpose if I were using a "trng", but I am using a pseudo random number generator.

Comment: OK, but using a `SecureRandom` is not the way to do it either. If you want to get perdicatable and secure OTPs, you need to use a real cryptographic key as the seed, not an integer (4 bytes). It would take a few hours to defeat our OTP. See updated answer (again).

Comment: The thing is the code I used in my question is just for an example. The method SecureRandom.setSeed(long a) accepts a long seed. The problem is not with the seed. The problem is with the implementation of the "SHA!PRNG" algrithm. However I will look into HMAC and let you know.

Comment: 8 bytes (long) is still short. Anyway, SHA1PRNG keeps an internal counter, which you cannot set via the `SecureRandom` interface. So, even you use the same seed, the 'OTP' will be the same only if you call the two instances exactly the same number of times. SO is not really a place for discussions, but getting OTP right is not that easy, read through the RFC before you decide on a course of action.

Comment: @nokolay elenkov: Obviously they will be the same only when you call them the same number of times. I have taken care of all that in my code. The only problem is that as I have repeated so many times. "The problem is with the implementation of the PRNG algorithm -SHA1PRNG".

Comment: PLease answer the question if you know the answer. Why do you want my code?

Comment: I am trying to tell that my code has no relation to the question that I've asked.

Comment: I am trying to tell you that I don't need to see your super secret code. But you are not being very clear, and that is not helpful.

Comment: Also, note that Android SecureRandom behaves differently than Java SecureRandom with regard to seeds. Only relevant if you expect portability to other Java platforms.

Comment: @GregS What do you mean? That it uses `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: Yes, Oracle's Java implementation will grab bytes from /dev/urandom even if you give it a seed. So it is not deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That's always been my understanding, but then all those samples for Android where people are doing `sr.setSeed("password".getBytes()); byte[] aesKey = sr.getBytes(256/8);` started popping up. BTW, do you know if there is a formal spec for SHA1PRNG? It seems the definition is fairly fuzzy.

Comment: @GregS : So are you telling that android uses native prng and not sha1 prng. Because only native prng uses /dev/random. If so can I get an implementation of sha1prng in android by some other provider.

Comment: @ashwin: No, that is not what I'm saying. I was talking about the Oracle Java platform, not the android platform.

Answer (score 5):

Did you add the following line?

> Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

The default Java Security does not contain the Bouncy Castle implementation, so you need to add the Bouncy Castle Provider to the list of providers available in memory before you can use it.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/SecureRandomSHA1PRNG.htm

Comment: remember to explain what you are recommending.

Comment: thanks for the comment - added a line about the need to add the provider to memory before it can be used